# Hamcrest Matchers for Java 8 LocalDate

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

I'd like to test if a java.time.LocalDate is within a fixed number of days of a test date and I'd like to use Hamcrest matchers if possible. Are there any matchers for Hamcrest (java) for working with Dates?

Answer (score 10):

There is a date matcher extension library for hamcrest, hamcrest-date, which can match LocalDate, LocalDateTime, ZoneDateTime, and Date. To compare if a LocalDate is within a number of days of a test date you can use this syntax:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import org.exparity.hamcrest.date.LocalDateMatchers;
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LocalDateTest {
  @Test
  public void isDate() {
    LocalDate actual = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate expected = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.OCTOBER, 15);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(actual, 
             LocalDateMatchers.within(5, ChronoUnit.DAYS, expected));
  }
}
```

The library can be included in you by adding this dependency to your pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The project is hosted on github at https://github.com/eXparity/hamcrest-date

Comment: Can you merge your code into hamcrest ?